# DOM Event Listener won't work in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've tried so many possible solutions and looked up documentation and so far nothing has worked. It's a very basic event listener that listens for a button click within the extension.

script.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
    var b = document.getElementById('calculate');
    b.addEventListener('click', displayDate(), false);
}
```

manifest.json

```
    {  
  "name": "RE-Toolkit",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Real Estate Toolkit",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["/script.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  //ICON
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "512": "/home-icon.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "/popup.html"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js", "popup.html"]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css" src="style.css"></style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="/home-icon.png" >
            <span>Date Calculator</span>
        </div>
        <p style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; color: grey;">Note: Rules are as follows: Up to (7) days, weekends and holidays are skipped in the count. After (7) days, weekends and holidays are included in the count. If the last day of any deadline falls on a weekend or holiday, the deadline is pushed to the next available day.</p> 
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <label for="start">Start date:</label>
            <input class="input" type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2020-01-01" min="2020-01-01" max="2020-12-31">
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <label for="days">Days to Deadline:</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" class="input" id="days">
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <button class="btn" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2 class="result"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I just overlooking basic permissions or something? I don't even want it to interact with a webpage. Essentially I just want to use it as an app that's stored in my browser for quick use.

Comment: Remove the "background" section from manifest.json. This section declares a separate hidden background page in addition to the popup page. You don't need that for this task. Also you don't need DOMContentLoaded because you already run the script at the end of the page so DOM is fully ready. Also remove web_accessible_resources, it exposes stuff to be injected into web pages.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. The documentation told me I should run it as a background script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The documentation is poorly worded. It meant API events, not DOM events.